# numeric undefined in datetime2 package

Tags: datetime2

I ran into a weird problem with the `\usepackage{datetime2}` (with `datetime2-english` installed). When I run the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=numeric]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{datesep={\space\&,\&\space}}
\begin{document}
\today\\
\DTMdisplaydate{2000}{01}{01}{}
\end{document}
```

the date is typeset correctly in both cases (i.e. with the datesep intentionally set to weird values [' &,& '] for demonstration purposes). This shows me, that the en-GB-numeric style seems to be used correctly. Nevertheless, I get three errors

```
! Package datetime2 Error: Unknown style `en-GB-regional'
```

and nine warnings

```
Package datetime2 Warning: No date style `en-GB-regional' defined on input line[...]
```

The same is true for `en-US`. However, in both cases there is absolutely no problem when I set `useregional=text`. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Nope, that makes things worse. The errors disappear, but only because then `\today` is redefined by babel and for `\DTMdisplaydate` uses the default instead of `en-GB`. So both dates are then not in the format I want, and worse not even consistently formatted. In the datetime2 manual this is hinted at and there also `datetime2` is always loaded after `babel`

Comment: Imho this is a typo at the end of `datetime2-en-GB.ldf`. `\DTMsetstyle{en-GB-regional}` should be `\DTMsetstyle{en-GB-numeric}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So you think it is a bug the author/maintainer should be informed about?

Comment: Yes, write Nicola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was truly a minor bug. It has now been fixed in v. 1.01 of datetime2-english.

[Bug Report](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=82)